# ArangoDB TransactionalGraph implementation for Blueprints

Tags: arangodb, tinkerpop

I'm trying to benchmark ArangoDB with [GraphDBBenchmark](https://github.com/Morro/GraphDBBenchmark), the problem is that the framework assumes that a graph database provides a Blueprints TransactionalGraph implementation. ArangoDB doesn't seem to have such in [blueprints-arangodb-graph](https://github.com/triAGENS/blueprints-arangodb-graph)
Is there a reason why Arango doesn't provide the TransactionalGraph functionality in its Blueprints API?
Can anyone point me to a sample Arango Blueprints TransactionalGraph implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that currently ArangoDB does not support that interface.  You can see from the "features" [definition](https://github.com/triAGENS/blueprints-arangodb-graph/blob/0e2a04296fbca103d8f9158ec1eea45c980439ba/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/impls/arangodb/ArangoDBGraph.java#L57) that `suppportsTransactions` is "false".